# Как в NSViewController ловить события изменения размера окна?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, resize

Как в NSViewController ловить события изменения размера окна?
Нужно перераспределить вложенные элементы, без использования constraints и IntefaceBuilder.

Comment: окно это `view`?

Comment: да NSViewController.view

Comment: чтоб ловить события изменения окна можно использовать KVO на "frame". а перераспределить вручную изменением того же frame

Comment: Спасибо получилось!

Comment: скопировал в ответ

Answer (score 2):

чтоб ловить события изменения окна можно использовать KVO на "frame". а перераспределить вручную изменением того же frame

Answer (score 0):

NSWindow имеет нотификейшины

```
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *NSWindowDidMoveNotification;
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *NSWindowDidResignKeyNotification;
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *NSWindowDidResignMainNotification;
APPKIT_EXTERN NSString *NSWindowDidResizeNotification;
```

Добавляете обсервер и слушаете

```
[pCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(windowDidResizeNotification:) name:NSWindowDidResizeNotification object:self];
```